# Compatibility with Dell XPS 13 (2 in one) - model 9310

Tags: dell

I was willing to buy a Dell XPS 13 2 in 1 (model **9310**) but the seller told me that it is not compatible with Ubuntu.

Could anybody confirm?

Thanks.

Comment: we do not provide hardware support. If hardware is not working someone that owns one should fie bug reports so the system does work.Plus getting Ubuntu to work on hardware  that is acting up might still be possible depending on your skill. Dell also has a site for Ubuntu specific hardware ;)

Comment: Dell XPS 13 9310 Intel Xe Graphics' Incredible Performance Uplift From OpenCL 
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel-xe-graphics&num=1

Answer (score 0):

I’m running it right now with Ubuntu 20.04. With the OEM kernel (`apt install linux-oem-20.04`) it works quite well. Currently only the fingerprint reader doesn't seem to work, and deep sleep seems an issue causing battery drain in suspend mode.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Vincent! The fingerprint is not an issue for me but camera and touchscreen are essential for my work. Then I think I am safe if I get it.

Comment: @Vincent how about camera, can you please confirm that camera works too?